# Installing and configuring OpsGenie Logstash plugin in Logstash 5.4

Tags: logstash, opsgenie

I am trying to install the OpsGenie output plugin ([`v2.0.5`](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-output-opsgenie)) in Logstash (`v5.4.2`).

According to the [OpsGenie instructions](https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/integrations/logstash-integration), one has to run:

```
bin/plugin install logstash-output-opsgenie
```

which in Logstash `5.4` [should be](https://github.com/opsgenie/logstash-output-opsgenie/issues/6):

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-opsgenie
```

Running this you get:

```
Looking if package named: logstash-output-opsgenie exists at https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-opsgenie/logstash-output-opsgenie-5.4.2.zip
```

(but there is no such artifact: `logstash-output-opsgenie-5.4.2.zip`)

Even trying to force the version:

```
$ DEBUG=1 bin/logstash-plugin install --version 2.0.5 logstash-output-opsgenie
```

you still get:

```
DEBUG: exec /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/bin/jruby /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb install --version 2.0.5 logstash-output-opsgenie
Looking if package named: logstash-output-opsgenie exists at https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-opsgenie/logstash-output-opsgenie-5.4.2.zip
Network error, skipping Elastic pack, exception: Connection refused - Connection refused
```

How can I install this Logstash output plugin?

Answer (score 1):

In the [OpsGenie instructions](https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/logstash-integration) under **Configuration on Logstash** section there is another link which directs to [OpsGenie's Logstash plugin](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-output-opsgenie). In that page there is a command to install the plugin which is

```
 gem install logstash-output-opsgenie
```

If the other logstash packages which OpsGenie's plugin depends on then running this command will install the plugin. After that , change the directory to the which logstash is in. Then run

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-opsgenie
```